# Log errors to file (PHP + IIS6 + FastCGI + Win2003 Server)

Tags: php, iis-6, error-logging

Though I have read lots of posts and pages concerning the issue (shown below), I guess I'm missing something here. The mais issue is: *my PHP errors are not being logged to the file specified nor to the system event log*.

[My phpinfo() shows](http://cativaimagem.com.br:8080/info.php): Windows Server 2003, PHP 5.3.6, log_errors = On, error_log = C:\\errorphp.log

I have tried both `error_log = C:\Inetpub\logs\php.log` and `error_log = syslog` in **php.ini** to no effect (either one at a time).

I have:

1. restarted IIS after every php.ini change
2. granted the IUSR_XXXXX User *Modify* permissions on the folder AND the file
3. tried leaving the directory blank and letting PHP create the file
4. had a headache.

Any help is much appreciated.

> references:
>
> - [PHP Manual - PHP on IIS 6](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php)
> - [Store PHP errors in a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114054/store-php-errors-in-a-log-file)
> - [IIS PHP doesn't log errors to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661688/iis-php-doesnt-log-errors-to-log-file)
> - [My php error log file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284993/my-php-error-log-file-is-empty)
> - [Running a defect php file cause error 500](https://serverfault.com/questions/397220/running-a-defect-php-file-cause-error-500)
> - [Logging PHP to Windows Event Log](http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/logging_php_to_windows_event_log)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, **setting**

```
fastcgi.logging = 1
```

**in php.ini** solved the issue and I do have the log file working now (I left the file creation to php itself, *my directory was blank*)

I'd never guess that as the php.ini itself states (right above the stated config)

> ; Disable logging through FastCGI connection. PHP's default behavior is to enable this feature.

Go figure.

Comment: this doesn't seem like a good solution to me anyway. On an error test page my server now returns 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: marquito, you should set your fastcgi settings error reporting to "IgnoreAndReturn200" which would let the PHP handle the error.

Comment: @marquito, How did you manage to find out that it is due to `fastcgi.logging = 1`?

Comment: man... that was 3 years ago. As long as I can remember correctly, I know that because I was changing configs one by one to see what was effective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you

- checked your error_reporting level
- tried setting a log file inside the document root (incl. permission to write) to see if any restrictions apply?

Comment: have not tried that, but I have tried something else, which was to set `fastcgi.logging = 1`. And it just worked. I wasn't aware I'd have to change this in order to have the logging working.

Comment: but thanks, Müller. My solution ain't good, though, as it makes the server return an HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) now instead of a blank page.