# Programmatically Find PHP Error Log File

Tags: php

I know that the PHP log file is located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` for my personal box, but I am interested in pragmatically finding out where the error log file is.

I have tried:

```
 ini_get('error_log');
```

But my php ini doesn't specify error_log, so it's blank. And since apache/ngnix each store different places, is there a way to find out where errors are being written to? I don't mind to use `exec()` to run a command to get it, but

```
php -i | grep error_log
```

Returns

```
error_log => no value => no value
```

For my set up

Answer (score 1):

To find error log file for command line PHP use:

```
php -i | grep error_log
```

To find error log file for web server - use build-in function:

```
phpinfo();
```

Remember that:

> **error_log** *string*
>
> Name of the file where script errors should be
>   logged. The file should be writable by the web server's user. If the
>   special value syslog is used, the errors are sent to the system logger
>   instead. On Unix, this means syslog(3) and on Windows NT it means the
>   event log. The system logger is not supported on Windows 95. See also:
>   syslog(). If this directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI
>   error logger. For example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in
>   CLI. See also error_log().

So when You get `error_log => no value => no value` it means log for Apache / ngnix will be used - as in Your configuration.

You can find more information about the `error_log` `php.ini` setting [here](https://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)

Answer (score 0):

You need [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo)

unfortunately it outputs rather than returning the information you need - but on that page quite a few folk have given examples of cathing the output